# Asking for an upvote to my *correct* answer to a 5-year-old question

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, voting

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Why would colder air disperse condensation on a car windshield?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/325820/2451)

Would a friendly moderator or two consider upvoting it? The previous answers are not very well thought out, but I cannot do anything to upvote my answer as I'm a new contributor. I would like to comment on the original accepted answer to inform them, but I can't do that either.

Comment: Did you mean "bump" or place a "bounty" by upvote?

Comment: I think bump by the typical definition. "consider upvoting" = please review my answer and upvote if correct/helpful. I should have let it wait a week or two first though before asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Honestly, asking people to upvote your answer is considered to be in bad taste. So the blunt answer is no, we won't upvote your answer because you asked us to.

What you can do, however, is post a link to your answer in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (if you have access to it) and invite people to read it and vote on it as they see fit. This is better than asking for upvotes since it's not viewed as you trying to bias the evaluation of your answer away from the true quality of the answer. If the answer is good, it should get more upvotes than downvotes anyway. And posting in chat is better than posting on meta because chat is less formal and less attention-grabbing than a meta post.

---

Incidentally, moderators have no special privileges or responsibilities when it comes to casting upvotes and downvotes, so the fact that you're asking a *moderator* specifically to do it also seems questionable.

Comment: Given the newness on the network, I wouldn't call asking for moderator intervention questionable. Most likely just a lack of understanding about how things work here viz. other internet forums. [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) and all.